# Bootstrap - Server-side validation

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a modal in Bootstrap 3 which collects some data.  If the entered ID already exists in a SQL table, I want to display a warning message in the modal - but the modal seems to disappear when the user clicks the [Save] button.

I can relaunch the modal which then correctly displays the exception - but the background becomes darker & darker each time the [Save] button is clicked.

Is there a more practical solution to prevent the modal from being closed if a server-side exception occurs - or at least to prevent the background from becoming progressively darker when the primary button is clicked?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping everything inside the modal in an asp. Net update panel? That should prevent the entire page from posting back and you losing the modal

Comment: Are you using MVC or Webforms?

Comment: Yup, I'm using an UpdatePanel.  I'm using ASP.NET Webforms.

Comment: I think UpdatePanel and Bootstrap modal are somewhat incompatible...

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you are interacting with the server inside a modal.  You need to handle the hide event to check the response from server before letting it bubble.

```
$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // check response from server and cancel event or let it bubble.
})
```

Comment: Thanks, should this code be added before the .modal('Show') statement, e.g.
`        sb.Append(@"<script type='text/javascript'>");
        sb.Append("$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {");
        sb.Append("  // do something...");
        sb.Append("}) ");

        sb.Append("$('#myModal').modal('show');");

        sb.Append(@"</script>");`

Comment: It shouldn't matter where you add it.  You are hooking up to an event that hasn't happened yet.

Comment: I've attempted to add the code before the .modal('show').  My test should always prevent the modal from disappearing (in the function I've added if (1==1) {return false}; - but the modal still insists on disappearing!  Any ideas?

Comment: probably need e.preventDefault()

Comment: it's moving in the right direction - the code is now invoked for the [Close] and [x] buttons - as they're the ones which call data-dismiss="modal", but the I really need this to work the other way round, i.e. clicking [Close] should close without any validation checks and clicking [Save] needs to invoke the hide.bs.modal code - any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

you need to handle event hide.bs.modal, do your validation and return false to prevent modal from closing

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-examples